# Notepad++ Console - unable to change the current drive

Tags: cmd, notepad++, drive, cd, nppexec

I've just discovered the NppExec console in Notepad++, which I would really like to use in place of opening up cmd instances. My 'Projects' folder is on the D drive, but Notepad++ is installed in C:/Program Files... I tried changing the current directory like so:

```
cd /D D:/Projects
```

This works fine in the normal Windows console, but in NppExec, it sends me to C:/

Any ideas for how I could get into D:/Projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `/D` flag:

```
cd D:\Projects
```

Comment: I feel like kicking myself. Thanks for the help. :)